# Stuck with view (MVC) using Entity Framework code-first approach

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting an error on View

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[oneToOneRelationship.Student]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[oneToOneRelationship.StudentDBContext]'.

While running the application, database is getting updated.

```
namespace oneToOneRelationship.Controllers    
{   
    public class StudentController : Controller    
    {    
        StudentDBContext objContext;     
        public StudentController()      
        {     
            objContext = new StudentDBContext();    
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Student s = new Student
            {
                StudentId = 1,
                StudentName = "Hitesh",
                StudentAge = 24
            };
            StudentAccount sa = new StudentAccount { 
                             StudentName = "Sports account",
                             StudentAmount = 300,
                             student = s
            };

            objContext.Students.Add(s);
            objContext.StudentAccounts.Add(sa);
            objContext.SaveChanges();

            var result = from r in objContext.Students select r;
            var data = objContext.Students.ToList();
            return View(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your view code? most possibly the model type is wrongly mentioned in the view file

Comment: @shakib@model IEnumerable<oneToOneRelationship.StudentDBContext>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

Comment: Edit your question (not in comments). And the view needs to be `@model IEnumerable<oneToOneRelationship.Student>`

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<oneToOneRelationship.StudentDBContext>` should be something like `@model IEnumerable<oneToOneRelationship.Student>`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks everyone